# HTML- how to insert the current time into web table (<td>)?

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to get a current date. but I want it to display after  tag using document.write function (well. it IS the demand :)/ )

I am trying " `<td>document.write(day)<td>` " in the table created in form and /form tags, day is the variable i defined in the `<script>` and it has the correct value;

but it doesn't show the correct info. Can someone tell me how to do that? (HAVE to use document.write function and DO NOT use this function to create a table tag like `<td>` or `<tr>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the javascript in the `<script>` tag.

```
<td><script>document.write(day);</script><td>
```

Alternatively, you could assign the td an id and then reference it later.

```
<td id="writeDay"></td>
...
<script>document.getElementById("writeDay").innerHTML = day;</script>
```

Or you could even make the whole element and then place it when you want

```
<td id="writeDay"></td>
<script>
 var dayElement = document.createElement("div");
 dayElement.innerHTML = day;
 function appendDay(target){
  document.getElementById(target).appendChild(dayElement);
 }
</script>
...
<script>appendDay("writeDay");</script>
```

Comment: assigning the id and writing to the DOM is a better option. See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @user1177245 - The script tag will fire up the javascript interpreter. Without it any scripting text used will be just text.